# How to set two table in Data Source in Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have an issue in Crystal Report where in , I need to print on Crystal Report where values comes from three tables:

1-teach_details
2-MasterTeacherDetails
3-MasterTeacherSpecimenDetails

So, for this I have used data table which has all the fields necessary. On crystal Report, Report header section has teach_details values , on detail section MasterTeacherDetails and then MasterTeacherSpecimenDetails , for this I have query as :

```
 Select teach_details.IdentityCode,IdentityName,dbo.fun_UniIdToUniName(UniId) as UniversityName,teach_details.Address+', '+dbo.fun_CityIdToCityName(teach_details.StateID,  teach_details.CityID)+', '+dbo.fun_StateIdToStateName(teach_details.StateID)+', '+teach_details.PinCode as IdentityAddress,  dbo.fun_GradeIdToGradeName(teach_details.Grade) as Grade,  case when teach_details.TypeOfIdentity='College' then dbo.fun_StrIdToStrName(teach_details.Streams)  else case when teach_details.TypeOfIdentity='Coaching' then dbo.fun_ExamIdToExamName(teach_details.Exam)  else dbo.fun_StanderdIdToStanderdName(teach_details.Standerd) end end as Strm_Exam_Standard, TeacherName+'/'+MasterTeacherDetails.TeacherCode as TeacherName, case when MasterTeacherDetails.TypeOfIdentity='College' then dbo.fun_StrIdToStrName(MasterTeacherDetails.Stream)  else case when MasterTeacherDetails.TypeOfIdentity='Coaching' then dbo.fun_ExamIdToExamName(MasterTeacherDetails.Exam)  else dbo.fun_StanderdIdToStanderdName(MasterTeacherDetails.Standerd) end end as TeacherStr_Exm_Stnrd,  case when SameAddress='True' then teach_details.Address+', '+dbo.fun_CityIdToCityName(teach_details.StateID, teach_details.CityID)+', '+dbo.fun_StateIdToStateName(teach_details.StateID)+', '+teach_details.PinCode else MasterTeacherDetails.Address+', '+dbo.fun_CityIdToCityName(MasterTeacherDetails.StateID,MasterTeacherDetails.CityID)+', '+dbo.fun_StateIdToStateName(MasterTeacherDetails.StateID)+', '+MasterTeacherDetails.PinCode end as TeacherAddress, MasterTeacherDetails.Mobile as TeacherMobileNo,MasterTeacherDetails.EmailID as TeacherEmailID,Case MasterTeacherDetails.DOB when '01/01/1900' then '' else Convert(varchar(10),MasterTeacherDetails.DOB,103) end as DOB,MasterTeacherDetails.Remark  ,BookCode,BookCode as BookName,BookCode as AuthorName,DispatchThrough as Mode,Qty  from teach_details inner join MasterTeacherDetails on teach_details.IdentityCode=MasterTeacherDetails.IdentityCode  inner Join MasterTeacherSpecimenDetails on MasterTeacherDetails.TeacherCode=MasterTeacherSpecimenDetails.TeacherCode  where  (teach_details.TypeOfIdentity ='College' and (teach_details.CityID = 'GHAZIA')) order by IdentityName
```

Now, the problem here is that MasterTeacherDetails and MasterTeacherSpecimenDetails have different number of rows,Suppose
MasterTeacherDetails has a,b,c and MasterTeacherSpecimenDetails has d,e,f,g,h

So when I run it with data it shows me 5 lines of entry and MasterTeacherDetails rows repeats itself 5 times, like :

[image]

Rather it should display:

[image]

I cannot use sub report for showing specimen details section and main report for showing Teacher Details Section.

So please help, and please try to be least technical as I am not very efficient on C#.net yet.

Comment: Looks like problem with linking..check links

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather by reading your question and comments, it seems like you would like a summary, then also have the specimen listings on separate pages for each teacher so that you can separate the report and give them each their listing.

Also, it seems that you want to do this with only one SQL query, meaning one command table.

I would begin with grouping by teacher for both sections of the report.

For the specimen detail section, you can hide the group header and footer. Use the group expert paging settings to create a new page after each teacher group to get each teacher on different pages to distribute the sections of the report. Also, you'll probably want the page numbers to restart after this group. I don't think you can do this through group expert; you'll probably need to do this through section expert on the group footer paging settings.

For the teacher detail section, also use the grouping by teacher to show the "teacher detail" in the group header or footer, then suppress the detail section using section expert. This will eliminate your multiple lines. I would put the teacher details in a sub-report in the report header section, and use the section expert to create a new page after the report header section. This is like a dedicated front page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I used the sub-reports.
Sir I want to show the details of teachers in Teacher details section and specimen copy's send to the particular teacher show in the below ( Specimen Details) Section by using single Sql query.

If you want then I show the representation of this problem on paper

Comment: It sounds to me that you're saying that you want a summary list at the beginning, then want a list of specimens that you can separate for each teacher?

Comment: I've changed my answer response.

Answer (score 0):

Please use DataSet instead

DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();

dsReport.Tables.Add(dataTable1);

dsReport.Tables.Add(dataTable2);

yourReport.SetDataSource(dsReport)